# Chart.js xAxes Date Labels are altered based on screen width

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs

I've been messing around with chart.js time options (`displayFormat` and `tooltipFormat`):

```
type: 'time',
unit: 'day',
unitStepSize: 1,
time: {
    displayFormats: {
        'day': 'dd',
    },   
    tooltipFormat: 'll'
},
```

Which works as expected - on a 17inch laptop screen.

This shows dates as `Mo`, `Tu`, `We`, `Th`, `Fr`, `Sa`, `Su`.

However on a 24inch monitor chart.js automatically alters the dates and they become:

`Aug 18 12AM` - `Aug 18 12PM`,  `Aug 19 12AM` - `Aug 19 12PM`, etc

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the **`hour`** property of `displayFormats` to **`dd`** as well, like so :

```
...
time: {
   displayFormats: {
      'day': 'dd',
      'hour': 'dd' //<-- set this
   },
   tooltipFormat: 'll'
},
...
```

Comment: :O so simple... Thank you!

Comment: I was too trigger happy on the upvotes :( does that work for you? doesn't for me

Comment: Thank you! It's to do with the data provided. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/gd3qrke1/ (still no solution). You had days at different intervals whereas mine always places each day.

Comment: Cheers, just realised that does Mo -  Mo, Tu - Tu... Can I stop that from happening?

Comment: Yes `unit: 'day'` would do it.. but it should be under `time`.. (`unitStepSize: 1` as well)

Comment: Already have that in my questions code above :( It makes my bar charts a mess lol EDIT sorry you meant wthin the time object? :L

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152845/discussion-between-daniel-cull-and-nd).